# Unable to connect to the GridDB Database Server

Tags: griddb

I am unable to connect to the GridDB Database server due to the client version discrepancy, as shown below:

```bash
[Server] 10054

[Description] Client version discrepancy
```

The incompatibility between the client and database versions is causing the error. However, I have updated my client and database version to the latest **v2.7**:

```bash
gs_stat -v 

GridDB version: 2.7.0
Client version: 2.7.0
...
```

The container schema and its connection port details are as follows:

```js
const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
const store = factory.getStore({
    "host": '239.0.0.1',
    "port": 31999,
    "clusterName": "defaultCluster",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
});

const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "usedcaranalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Sales_ID", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["year", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["selling_price", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["km_driven", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["Region", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["State or Province", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["City", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["fuel", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seller_type", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["transmission", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["owner", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["mileage", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["engine", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["max_power", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["torque", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seats", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["sold", griddb.Type.STRING]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});
```

After the installation, I tried restarting my pc, but it did not help. What is the possible issue here?

Comment: I don't think GridDB v2.7 is around anymore. Please check what version you are again and try using the latest V5.x version: https://github.com/griddb/griddb/releases/tag/v5.3.0